# pager replaced in ajax callback

Tags: ajax, database, paging

I have a page with multiple elements and pager. They are both created in the same function. Next to this i have a search box, and after clicking "search", ajax callback calls this same function and creates elements with pager depending on search term. This is working fine.

The problem is that once i search something, the first page shows results regarding the search but next pages don't. Like the pager didn't update which next items should show?!

my code is similar to this:

```
function mymodule_page() {
// this will be filled with an array of our content
$build = array();

// basic select query
$select = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->extend('PagerDefault') // this adds the pager
  ->limit(10)

// execute the query
$nids = $select->execute()->fetchCol();

// do something to output your results here.
foreach ($nids as $nid) {
$content .= $nid;
}
// add the content
$build['content'] = array('#markup' => $content)

// Add the pager
$build['pager'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'pager',
  '#weight' => 5,
);

// return the renderable array
return $build;
}
```

Comment: Are you using ajax for pager also?

Comment: no, i replace "system/ajax" with normal url becouse it is not working with ajax. at least by default.

Comment: OK.. Are you creating page using custom module or views? Could you share your code? If you are using ajax for searching and ajax for pager then you need to update your ajax for pager after searching.

Comment: I am using custom module for rendering output. How can i update pager? I recreate it each time, i thought this would be enough. Number of pages change correctly.

Comment: What is functionality of the custom_search function? I am not getting "I recreate it each time".

Comment: On first page load and after each search, this function get's called. So every time pager gets recreated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10466/discussion-between-gregab-and-jayendra-kainthola)

Comment: Chat is blocked in my office. Sorry for that.

Comment: any ideas how can i fix this?

Comment: Could you provide your complete code for rendering search and pagination, so I will check and let you know.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I think it's because the callback reloads the form using the original path and ignores the page parameters.  Did you ever resolve this?  I'm trying to learn how to use the 'path' parameter.